# (2n log(n) + n) anagram detection function not much slower than 4n + 26 function despite huge n

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity

I have 2 anagram detection functions; one uses sort and compare and the other keeps track of the number of occurences of each alphabetical character.

Assume here that the two strings passed to the functions are identical, the first randomly generated (unsorted) and the second = to the first, so that both functions execute "all the way" and return True.

According to my algorithmic analysis (obviously probably wrong...), the first function should be 2 * n log(n) + n, and the second function 2 + 2n + 2n + 26 = 28 + 5n.

```
def anag1(s1, s2):      
    s1 = list(s1)
    s1.sort()
    s2 = list(s2)
    s2.sort()

    for i in range(len(s1)):
        if s1[i] != s2[i]:
            return False

    return True

def anag2(s1, s2):
    l1 = [0] * 26
    l2 = [0] * 26
    for i in s1:
        k = ord(i) % 26
        l1[k] += 1
    for i in s2:
        k = ord(i) % 26
        l2[k] += 1

    return l1 == l2
```

For 2 strings of 100,000 characters, this should mean that the first function would be 3.4 million time units vs 400,000 time units for the second function.

In other words, **the second function should be close to 8 times faster than the first**.

However, when I time the execution of both function, the second one is not even twice as fast as the first. For 2 strings of 100,000 characters, the first function executes in 0.085s and the second in 0.055s.

**What's going on**?

Comment: How do you measure the time? Did you subtract setup time? Can you perhaps test with a large n, something that takes closer to a few tens of seconds to run?

Comment: @EmilVikström, I'm using start = time.time(), end = time.time() within the functions and then end-start to get the difference. I just tried with strings of 10 million and it's basically the same; 9.3s for the first and 5.6s for the second. Start = time.time() is the first statement in the functions, and end = time.time() the last just before return.

Comment: What does `ord` function do? What are your inputs? Runtime complexity of `sort()` function might be close to o(n) for some inputs.

Comment: @bekce, ord() gives the ascii value for a character, inputs are two strings randomly generated. Second one is a copy of the first to make sure the functions go "all the way" and return True.

Comment: Analysing worst case and measuring "average"? (An introsort might even switch to counting.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theoretical complexity may have little with actual time spent. Consider:

- Various complexity of single operations (e.g. division vs addition)
- Memory access (bad cache hit ratio due to frequent random access on huge arrays can slow it down to more than half)
- Compiler / interpreter optimizations
- etc.

And not every sort is `O(n log (n))`

- Counting sort, Bucket Sort, Radix Sort are all `O(n)` or close to.

Edit:
I implemented both in Java on 100M number long array. It was 383 vs. 161 ms. On 10M the times were almost equal.

- Your 100k long array is way too small to warm up optimizers.
- Java uses DualPivotQuickSort, which runs almost `O(n)` on arrays with many duplicate values (small character cardinality). Your language may use something similar.

Comment: Thanks for going through the trouble of implementing the functions yourself. I'm amazed that the times are almost equal with 10M character strings, although I'm getting a smaller than 1:2 ratio myself in python with 10M chars. I have to look into those sort implementations you mention; I was going with the assumption that sort was always O(n log(n)). I guess I also should look into memory access considerations, I didn't realize that kind of stuff could make such a difference.

Comment: O(n) sorting is all about memory access. In the past I was doing a project on improving sorting effectiveness on big data. The result was BucketSort aware of cache hit ratio. That improved its performance 3 times and so it hugely outperformed RadixSort (that is considered to be the fastest algo) Even the RadixSort running times vary based on radice size. My computer likes 7-9 bit long radices, the more you give the less cache hit rattio you get, but smaller radices require more passes. Trade-off, you know. (end of a little cache fairy tale)

Answer (score 2):

Not all primitive functions take the same amount of time.  For example, your second method includes divisions, which often take more CPU cycles than other operations.  While the first function is O(n log(n)) and the second is O(n), you don't know what the constant factor is.

What your analysis really indicates is that, if you now do it with million character strings, you should see that the difference in speeds widens.

Comment: Actually i just did it with 10 million characters and the ratio is almost the same. 9.3s for the first function and 5.6s for the second. I saw someone using ord(i) - ord('a') in order to get values from 0 to 25 but I tested that independently and modulo is actually faster, although maybe still very slow.